# jQuery works and doesn't work when it first loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that I'm trying to implement some jQuery in.

I have two scripts, one that works on first load, and one that requires a reload. I had a problem with the one that works now where I modified the turbolinks in application.js. Now the same problem is happening to another script.

The one that works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//set animation timing
var animationDelay = 5000,
    //loading bar effect
    barAnimationDelay = 3800,
    barWaiting = barAnimationDelay - 3000, //3000 is the duration of the transition on the loading bar - set in the scss/css file
    //letters effect
    lettersDelay = 50,
    //type effect
    typeLettersDelay = 150,
    selectionDuration = 500,
    typeAnimationDelay = selectionDuration + 800,
    //clip effect 
    revealDuration = 600,
    revealAnimationDelay = 1500;

initHeadline();
```

The one that doesn't work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//if you change this breakpoint in the style.css file (or _layout.scss if you use SASS), don't forget to update this value as well
var MQL = 1170;

//primary navigation slide-in effect
if($(window).width() > MQL) {
    var headerHeight = $('.box-header').height();
    $(window).on('scroll',
    {
        previousTop: 0
    }, 
    ...
    ...
```

so on so forth.

Why is this happening? Is there a problem with the CSS or the page in which it's being called?

Comment: How did you modify turbolinks in `application.js`?

Comment: I rearranged it so it's like this:
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks

Comment: What happens if you disable turbolinks entirely by commenting out its `require`?

Comment: it works! so turbolinks was the culprit?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.2.6

Comment: That's good to hear. Check out my answer for Rails 4.2 and higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turbolinks can cause problems in your Rails app because it tries to save overhead by maintaining assets listed in the `<head>` element of your page (among other things). When you load a page using a full load (via refresh button), an actual ready event takes place and your scripts work. On the other hand, if you were to visit a page some other way (via link), Turbolinks tries to reuse the `<head>` element, so there's no ready event fired.

The solution in the past was to simply disable Turbolinks, either entirely, by removing its require line in application.js or by link (data: {no_turbolink: true}). With Rails 4.2.x and 5.x, you can listen for a Turbolinks related event that should work where a normal ready event would have worked before.

From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks):

> However, because Turbolinks overrides the normal page loading process,
>   the event that this relies on will not be fired. If you have code that
>   looks like this

```
$(document).ready ->
  alert "page has loaded!"
```

> you must change your code to do this instead:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  alert "page has loaded!"
```

(quote rearranged slightly for clarity)